# Docker exec: ipconfig failing

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

When following the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/building-net-docker-images) for Docker and .NET Core *Build and run the sample with Docker for Linux containers* ran fine but *Build and run the sample with Docker for Windows containers* fails with a strange error.

```
cd aspnetapp
docker build -t aspnetapp .
docker run -it --rm --name aspnetcore_sample aspnetapp
```

Then in a second cmd/PS

```
docker ps
docker exec aspnetcore_sample ipconfig
```

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:295: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"ipconfig\": executable file not
>   found in $PATH": unknown

Searching comes up empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution became obvious after trying a docker project with Visual Studio 2017 and using the [add docker support that VS17 has built in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQ6q9NfJtuc) .

Building after adding docker support to a new .NET Core MVC project:

> Done building project "docker-compose.dcproj" -- FAILED.
>
> Volume sharing is not enabled. Enable volume sharing in the Docker CE for Windows Settings.

Right-click docker taskbar icon - settings, shared drives (select the drive with code in it)

Running again.

> Your Docker server host is configured for 'Linux', however the docker-compose project targets 'Windows'.   docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets 165

Had to right-click docker taskbar, "Switch to Windows Containers", required an install or update and after a reboot selecting it again. Fixed.